# How to add a loadingLomponent or errorComponent to Vue3 in TypeScript via code splitting/lazy loading

Tags: typescript, lazy-loading, vuejs3, code-splitting

I want to add a loading spinner component, as long as the data from the api has not arrived.
I worked before in Vue2 + JavaScript and are super new to Vue3 + TypeScript.

I tried to archive it like that, but fail (different attempts of loading the TheCustomersTable are commented out above loader:)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { computed, defineComponent, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
    import CustomersModule from "@/store/modules/customers";
    // import TheCustomersTable from "@/components/Elements/customers/TheCustomersTable.vue";
    import LoadingSpinner from "@/components/Elements/LoadingSpinner.vue";
    // import BaseFilter from "@/components/Elements/Filter/BaseFilter.vue";
    
    // LoadingSpinner: (): Promise<defineAsyncComponent> => import('@/components/Elements/LoadingSpinner.vue')
    
    const TheCustomersTable = defineAsyncComponent({
        // loader: (import ("@/components/Elements/Filter/BaseFilter.vue")) /*webpackChunkName: "user" */,
        // loader: import ("@/components/Elements/customers/TheCustomersTable.vue") /*webpackChunkName: "user" */,
// loader: (): Promise<defineAsyncComponent> => import('@/components/Elements/customers/TheCustomersTable.vue'),
        loader: import('@/components/Elements/customers/TheCustomersTable.vue'),
        // loader: TheCustomersTable,
        loadingComponent: LoadingSpinner,
        delay: 2000,
        suspensible: false,
        // errorComponent: ErrorCmp,
        timeout: 3000
    })
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: "CustomersView",
      components: {
        // LoadingSpinner,
        // BaseFilter,
        TheCustomersTable
      },
```

Unfortunately I do not find much material, to how to pull that off

Comment: In addition:
I tried as well importing "by ...     loader: () => import ("@/components/Elements/customers/TheCustomersTable.vue") /*webpackChunkName: "user" */,
    loadingComponent: () => import ("@/components/Elements/LoadingSpinner.vue") /*webpackChunkName: "user" */," in const CustomerTable.
No errors, but no LoadingSpinner either :/

Answer (score 1):

I have handled it better using v-if, this is my code

```
<template>
  <Banner :currentPage="currentPage" :previousPage="previousPage" />

    <section class="section">
            <div class="container" v-if="!isLoading"> //add v-if !isLoading
               // rest of codes
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <Loading /> //keep a separate page/Componet that will display when APIs are not ready
            </div>
        </section>
</template>
```

then in your Javascript

```
<script>
import Banner from '@/components/Banner.vue'
import SingleJob from '@/components/SingleJob.vue'
import Loading from '@/views/custom/Loading.vue' // include Loading Component 
export default {
  name: 'Jobs',
  emits: ["paginate"],
  components: {
    Banner, SingleJob,
    Loading,
  },
  data(){
      return {
        search: '',
    
        isLoading: true, // isLoading should be true so that your page will start loading first
        jobs: {current_page: 1},
        allJobs: {},
        data: {},
        errors: false,
      }
  },
  methods: {
    getJobs(page){
      if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
        page = 1
      }
      this.isLoading =  true
      axios.get('/jobs?page=' + page).then(response => {
          this.jobs = response.data
      }).catch(errors => {
          this.errors = errors.response.data.errors
      }).finally(() => {   //set this finally it after your Api call
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.isLoading =  false  //set isloading to false
            }.bind(this), 200); //time delay
        })
    },
    
    }
  },

  mounted () {
  this.getJobs()
  this.getFilteredJobs()
  this.getCategories()
  this.getCountries()
}
}
</script>
```

in Loading component you can put anything that will display when loading. such as picture or animation or you can copy here

```
<template>
  <div class="loading-wrap">
      <div class="loading">
          <div class="loading-dots"><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>
.loading-wrap{
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.title{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.dot{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: blink 1.4s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80%{
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}

.dot:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #156394;
}
.dot:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #8ec73a;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.dot:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #156394;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.dot:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #8ec73a;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
</style>
```

Best of Luck

Comment: Hi @WillianBabuu, thank you, for your suggestion.
In the meanwhile I did it the same way. It works great.

But, the vue suggestions looks so neat and clean. I would really like to make use of it. (error component and delay look handy, too).
It seems to be connected, that the data comes from the api and uses v-if (or so)

Otherweise, would it be possible, to build something like a decorator.
So that I do not need to it into each desired component, but just add a little something?

Or a vue directive, which passes in a loading and error component and sets v-if at the right place ...?

Comment: hi @Ehrlich_Bachman, if i got you well. You mean you could reuse the components right. The Loading components you can use it everywhere You just need to include it. Or maybe i did not get well your comment

Comment: Hi @WillianBabuu, yeah, that is what I usually would do. But I thought, since I would want to include it in most components, maybe there is a lessy copy+paste way to do it.

On the other hand insert one global, component, might be less hustle then writing a directive or decorator.

Thanks for the nice exchange.

Comment: @Ehrlich_Bachman for me Registering components would do. You can include component to any page. I too did the same the same loading page is everywhere. Can you also Accept my answer. That would be great too

Comment: Yeah, but it does not address, how I can make use of i. e. loadingLomponent or errorComponent.
That seems the best work around so far and I used that approach before too, but not how to use that nice looking feature.

I try to get down to it.